# Input vs forward iterator

Tags: stl, c++

Доброго времени суток
Есть такой пример

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    istream_iterator<int> istrIt1(cin);
    istream_iterator<int> istrIt2;

    int arr[]={12,22,5,4,5,6};
    vector<int> v(arr,arr+6);
    min_element(istrIt1,istrIt2);

    return 0;
}
```

Можно ли в алгоритмах std::min_element и std::max_element использовать istream_iterator и везде ли это будет работать? Просто в стандарте написано, что они принимают forward iterator, а на практике оказывается, что и input iterator здесь отлично работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator),

> в отличие от `InputIterator`'а, `ForwardIterator` гарантирует валидность при использовании в многопроходных алгоритмах.

Если в вашей реализации STL `min_element` однопроходный, должно работать. Но гарантировать может только стандарт.

---

Как верно подсказывает [[@dzhioev](/users/552/dzhioev)](/users/552/dzhioev), `InputIterator` имеет право инвалидировать уже «пройденные» итераторы. Но `min_element` возвращает итератор, который скорее всего есть копия входного итератора. Так что здесь могут быть проблемы.

С другой стороны, для персистентных структур (`std::vector` и т. п.) он этого скорее всего не делает, но гарантии снова-таки нет. Для `cin` вполне возможно, что использование `istream_iterator`'а есть undefined behaviour. Поэтому лучше для не надеяться на случай, а «материализовать» введённую последовательность.

[Стандарт, 25.4.7/21](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3691.pdf) требует, чтобы входные параметры удовлетворяли требованиям `ForwardIterator`, но документация на VS 2013 непоследовательна: [[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cte9w4zx.aspx), [[2]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fz4h74cb%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Поэтому лучше делать так, как гарантировано работает по стандарту (тем более, это не так сложно).

Comment: Так min_element возвращает итератор указывающий на искомый элемент. А при инкременте input итератора могут быть инвалидированы его копии. Так что тут и с однопроходным алгоритмом проблемы могут быть.

Comment: @dzhioev: Ох, и правда. Обновлю-ка я ответ. Спасибо!

---
Обновил.